# How to convert SQL Server CTE query to Oracle 10G

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql, oracle10g, sqlplus

I have problem, because I get error unsupported column aliasing and I don't know where is the cause. Does anyone know the answer and can help?

I have tried it but I get an error:

> ORA-32033: unsupported column aliasing.

I am just trying to start using CTEs in Oracle (I am coming from T-SQL).

```
;with cte as
(
    select 
        ITP_NO, FROM_DATE,
        DATEADD(YEAR,cast(BILL_AMOUNT/ 58 as int)-1, FROM_DATE) as lastfromdate,
        BILL_AMOUNT
    from 
        test123 

    union all

    select 
        c.ITP_NO, DATEADD(YEAR,1, c.FROM_DATE) as fromdate,
        c.lastfromdate,
        t.BILL_AMOUNT
    from 
        cte c, test123 t
    where 
        c.ITP_NO = t.ITP_NO 
        and DATEADD(YEAR,1, c.FROM_DATE) <= c.lastfromdate 
)
,ctee as
(
      select CAST(t.ITP_NO as varchar(15)) ITP_NO,
      c.FROM_DATE, CAST( DATEADD(d,-1, DATEADD(YEAR, 1,c.FROM_DATE)) as date) as todate
      ,t.BILL_AMOUNT
      from test123 t, cte c
      where t.ITP_NO = c.ITP_NO
)
select  ITP_NO,FROM_DATE,todate,
left(datename(month, FROM_DATE),3)+' '+CAST(year(FROM_DATE)as varchar(10))+' - '+left(datename(month, todate),3)+' '+CAST(year(todate)as varchar(10)) ExpiryDate 
,BILL_AMOUNT
from ctee
order by 1 desc
```

I have tried below code but I get an error :

> ORA-32033: unsupported column aliasing.

```
;with cte
as
(
      select ITP_NO,
             FROM_DATE,
             add_months(FROM_DATE, (cast(BILL_AMOUNT/ 58 as int)-1)* 12) as lastfromdate 
              ,BILL_AMOUNT
      from test123 
      union all
      select c.ITP_NO, 
              add_months(c.FROM_DATE,12) as lastfromdate 
              ,c.lastfromdate 
              ,t.BILL_AMOUNT
      from cte c,test123 t
      where c.ITP_NO = t.ITP_NO and  add_months(c.FROM_DATE,12) <= c.lastfromdate 
)
,ctee
as
(
      select CAST(t.ITP_NO as varchar(15)) ITP_NO,
      c.FROM_DATE, 
      (add_months(c.FROM_DATE,12)-1)
      ,t.BILL_AMOUNT
      from test123 t, cte c
      where t.ITP_NO = c.ITP_NO
)
select  *
--ITP_NO,FROM_DATE,todate,
--left(datename(month, FROM_DATE),3)+' '+CAST(year(FROM_DATE)as varchar(10))+' - '+left(datename(month, todate),3)+' '+CAST(year(todate)as varchar(10)) ExpiryDate 
--,BILL_AMOUNT
from ctee
order by 1 desc
```

Comment: Two questions: What is this is the second CTE `(add_months(c.FROM_DATE,12)-1)` ?  And also why the semicolon to start your CTE in both cases?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen by removing the ; same error occurred .The second CTE used for reference,Basically I have to find the gap of years from From_date and To_Date column ,to_date is depend upon the Bill_Amount Paid by user.EX: If user paid 232 for a period from 01-10-2012 then his To_date will be 30-Sep-16 this is present in table, now  number of year gap is 4 hence I have to display year wise like Oct12-Sept13  Oct13 -Sept14 Oct14 -Sept15 Oct15-Sept16                                                                                                           row by against every ITP_NO column.

Comment: Without regard to the correctness of your query, my answer below may fix the immediate error.

Comment: Oracle 10 does not support recursive CTEs. You need to re-write that using `connect by`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for clearing things up here.

Comment: (add_months(c.FROM_DATE,12)-1) has no aliased name